# Attempting to make nested questions appear dynamically... C# ASP.Net Database First,

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Idea for making elements visible or invisible:
So… how the loop works right now is it for each category, it loops through each question in each category.
The idea is:  Each question can be answered yes or no, and then for each question answered yes, there can be up to 5 dates added.
What I want to do:

```
-If yes, first date appears:
-If the first date is answered, then a second question appears, and so on.
```

These questions are stored in a sql server like so:

I want only the inner loop to have this ability to be visible or invisible..
My thought is to do a nested loop and check check on each element.

[image]

//Psuedo code

```
//For each first question which has 5 sub questions that are all set to hidden:
var questioncount = (count of the first questions)
for(int i = 0; i<questioncount; i++){
    // set first variable to hold the first questions object.
    var element(‘#questionElement’ + i);
    // set firstElement to selected answer
    var isAnsweredYes = firstElement.(‘Yes’);
    for int j = 0; i<subQuestionCount; j++)
    if (isAnsweredYes == True){
        // jQuery selector to get an element
        var query = $('#element' + j);
        // check if element is Visible
        var isVisible = query.is(':visible');
        if (isVisible === true) {
            // element is Visible
            // do nothing
        } else {
            // element is Hidden
        query.show();
    }
    else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Does my logic seem forward? or can anyone advise me in a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use a button that says "Add another date", which is displayed under the last date field as soon as at least one is visible. That way you won't have to decide on a certain number (e.g. 5) as the maximum, plus I think it's a rather intuitive way of extending a form.
On each press of the button, create new input controls; be it in javascript or server side, it makes no real difference.

Comment: This is a good answer... I'll attempt it.
so then I guess I would use a on change event on the yes or no question?
How would I do a check change event inside of a loop like that in order to trigger the first to be visible?

Comment: Yes, look for OnChange on the yes/no dropdown. If it's being set to "no", hide the entire section containing date inputs. If it's being set to yes, remove any existing date inputs (if the yes/no has been toggled before), set "dateCount = 1", and create date inputs looping from 0 to "dateCount".
I'm not sure about your outer loop and what it's purpose is. You probably don't want to add event listeners in a loop either way, it should be added before or after so it only happens once, or you will get odd results.